# broken regulator pins

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, pins

A nooby question:  I installed new LDO regulators on the power supply section of a PCB, and one of the pins severed when I bent it down to screw on to the board (two of the others did not sever but have exposed copper).

I soldered the broken pin back together and am getting continuity again across all the pins, however the unit is not powering on.

Even though I was very quick with the solder is it possible I fried the IC because I was closer to it with the iron?

It also seems possible that the outer surface of the pin is what is joined, not necessarily the copper core- will this make a difference?  Unfortunately I don't have an independent power supply to test the regulator, so I'm just trying to get a feel for what could have gone wrong or if it's potentially something else.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's possible you damaged it, but not terribly likely. I would look for problems elsewhere.

Comment: how are you powering on the board now? is LDO input section alive?

Comment: Continuity across all pins? That is very suspicious. Are you using a multimeter on a low Ohms scale? (say 1000 Ohms or so). If you have continuity there (say less than 1 Ohm), you are in trouble. Either you shortcircuited the pins, or the regulator is dead.

Comment: Depending on how badly the lead was abused during assembly, the lead frame may be damaged inside the package.

If you have extras, I would try a new part -- saves time. Also, lead bending is a non-trivial pursuit. See http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-1031.pdf for guidance (as one example, YMMV).

Comment: I have never burned out an LDO when soldering, but I suppose it depends how hot the iron was. If possible, as @PKL recommended, just try a different one and test it before you bend it.

Comment: @jcoppens, I understood that statement as "there is continuity from one end of the lead to the package", as in, the lead is no longer visibly broken.

Comment: Yes, the pins are now continuous rather than broken in half, which is why I'm surprised that it would still be malfunctioning.  One problem is that the pins were lead-free so probably more brittle.  I guess I'll order another one and try that.

Comment: It's not the leads that are lead-free (well, they are too, as they are normally copper), just the solder. I doubt you will notice a difference in flexibility. Thanks for explanation on the shorts. Did you power up the regulator while the lead was open?

Comment: A follow-up to @Mewa's point, for clarification: I meant mechanical damage, not thermal. Unless care is taken to do it gently and maintain a good bend radius, the leads break quite readily, sometimes after just a few sharp bends.

Comment: @jcoppens, I fixed the leads before powering anything up.  PKL, the leads definitely cracked the first time I tried to bend them.  I wouldn't have guessed it was so delicate!  Why don't they just use standard lead wires?

Comment: As I told you before - the leads are still copper (or sometimes iron). It's only the tinning of the leads that has to be lead-free. Else the components cannot be in equipment to be exported to Europe (because of the EU RoHS laws - lead is considered a hazardous substance)

Comment: I meant "standard leads," not "standard lead(Pb) wires." Like the leads that come on caps...

Comment: @jcoppens or anyone else, can I test the regulator with a 9V battery as a power supply?  Can I test it while it's still on the PCB?  I rechecked everything and all connections to other PCB nodes seem OK.  So maybe I damaged the regulator by bending it?  It's just weird..

Comment: Yes, on the 9V test. Testing it on the board - depends. If the power consumption of the load side of the regulator is low enough, yes (too). A 9 V battery can only supply that maybe 200 - 300 mA (and at that current the output voltage won't be 9V anymore. Eg, Duracell at 100mA drops to 7V).

Comment: Hi @jcoppens and everyone.  Let's say, hypothetically, that someone were to install the voltage regulators backwards because the diagram has them reversed with how they're seated on the board.  Then let's say this hypothetical moron plugged the unit in and tryed it out :(  After realizing his or her mistake, this person switched the regulators but continues to see no power.  What components could this this poor have fool damaged?  Is this person hosed?